# Difference between WSUS and SCCM

Tags: sccm, windows-users, sccm-2007

What is the difference between **WSUS** and **SCCM** ? What is the **cost** involved for licensing ? Planning to deploy for around **300 clients** in **3 different countries**.

Comment: please ask a specific programming question

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Did you flag as off-topic? I close-voted because I do not perceive this a as a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

WSUS is the Microsoft's basic offering for enterprise OS and Microsoft application patching. It is capable of connecting to Microsoft's update catalogue, has a small amount of configuration around scheduling rollouts by groups etc, and limited reporting details on patch deployment.

SCCM has a system role called Software Update Point (SUP). This role has to be installed on WSUS server. When it is set, SCCM can manage updates catalog and binaries to make updates packages. Such as WSUS, packages can be created regarding to classification, products, languages of the update. Once these updates packages is created, it can be deployed with SCCM and use its powerful scheduler.

SCUP (System Centre Updates Publisher) could expand WSUS updates in SCCM. This builds on top of the WSUS infrastructure and components and gives you massively more configuration and reporting, as well as having the ability to connect to other vendors' update catalogues (Adobe, Dell, HP, etc) and also deploy your own custom patches for any apps.

For the detailed information about licensing System Center 2012 R2. :[System Center 2012 R2 Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/product-licensing/system-center-2012-r2.aspx#tab=1)